# Is an early bound interface and a late bound implementation possible with C#

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

I'm trying to create what is essentially a plugin framework for a project.  I'm trying to work out the pieces before full blown development and I've run into a problem.  I am building a message processor.  Where the message comes from determines how the message should be processed.  As retrieving the message and sending the message will be the same no matter where the message comes from, I felt that a plugin framework would be a good way to implement this.

I built an interface that all Implementations could be built against.

IIPInterfaces.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace IIPInterfaces
{
public interface IInterfaceProcessor
{
    IIPResult ProcessRequest(XmlDocument xdoc, String processType);
}

public class IIPResult
{
    public XmlDocument ResponseDocument { get; set;}
    Boolean IsSuccessful { get; set; }
    String Error { get; set; }
}
}
```

I created a implementation for the interface just to test it out.

PrototypeIIP

```
using IIPInterfaces;
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace PrototypeIIP
{
public class IIPImplimentation : IInterfaceProcessor
{
    public IIPResult ProcessRequest(XmlDocument xdoc, String requestType)
    {
        IIPResult result = new IIPResult();

        Console.WriteLine("In interface {0}", requestType);

        return result;
    }
    }
}
```

And then I created a test project to try to bind the implementation file at runtime and then use the interface.

Console Program

```
using IIPInterfaces;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml;

namespace LateBindingPrototype
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String filePath = "C:\\XMLConfig\\PrototypeIIP.dll";

        // Try to load a copy of PrototypeIIP
        Assembly a = null;
        try
        { a = Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath); }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
        if (a != null)
        { CreateUsingLateBinding(a); }

        Console.ReadKey();

        InvokeProcessMessage(a);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void InvokeProcessMessage(Assembly asm)
    {
        try
        {
            Type processor = asm.GetType("PrototypeIIP.IIPImplimentation");
            IInterfaceProcessor myProcessor = Activator.CreateInstance(processor) as IInterfaceProcessor;
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            myProcessor.ProcessRequest(xdoc, "test");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    static void CreateUsingLateBinding(Assembly asm)
    {
        try
        {
            Type processor = asm.GetType("PrototypeIIP.IIPImplimentation");

            object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(processor);
            Console.WriteLine("Created a {0} using late finding!", obj);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
}
```

The CreateUsingLateBinding Method works fine but when I try to create in instance of IInterfaceProcessor in the InvokeProcessMessage method the object is null.

Is what I am trying to do possible?  I know that I could do this by bypassing the interface and calling the methods directly from the implementation dll but I was hoping to keep the code cleaner than that because others in our development group will need to support this and simpler is better when it comes to some of them.

Thanks!

Comment: Basically you want IoC (Inversion of Control).  Take a look at Unity (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647202.aspx) or MEF (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291628.aspx).

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong with what you're attempting here. I don't have VS running at the moment, however, so hopefully someone else will jump in and pinpoint your error.

Comment: Where did you define the interface, and are you using the same reference assembly to define the interface file in both the implmentation dll and the program running your example code. (If you have A.dll and B.exe is `IInterfaceProcessor` defined in both A and B, just B, or C.dll that both A and B have a reference to)

Comment: I don't have an issue running your code and creating instances from both methods, the only issue I see is that the return type of `ProcessRequest` is `string` in your interface but `IIPResult` in your implementation.

Comment: Prestion -  Both are IIPResult.  String was from thinking about one thing and typing another.

Comment: Scott - Each piece is in its own file.  I created a Class library project to define the IInterfaceProcessor and IIPImplimentation.  LateBindingPrototype is a console application.  Both IIPlmplimentation and LateBindingPrototype have references to IInterfaceProcessor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious explanation for the problem you describe is that the interface type `IInterfaceProcessor` you use in your DLL when declaring the type that implements the interface is not the same interface type (also named `IInterfaceProcessor`) you use in your program when you try to create the instance.

I.e. the `Activator.CreateInstance()` actually returns a non-null reference (as it always will, unless an exception is thrown), but that type does not implement the interface you are trying to cast it to with the `as` operator.

The most common reason I've seen this happen is that a type is declared in some .cs file, but rather than compiling that .cs file into a single DLL and referencing the type via that DLL, the file is linked into two or more projects, compiled into each project separately. This results in a new type, one for each assembly, and of course the types are incompatible.

Granted, lacking [a good, complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can't say for sure that this is in fact the problem in your code. It's just an educated guess.

All that said, for the type of thing you seem to be trying to do, it is probably better to use the [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx). It provides a useful API on which to build exactly this kind of functionality.

Barring that, I assume that the hard-coded type names in your program are just for testing purposes. Of course, for a true plug-in architecture, you would want to simply enumerate all the types in an assembly, looking for those that implement the interface(s) you are interested in.

Comment: While I am not sure how what I posted lacked completeness, I've added the few using statements and file names into my post that was not there before.  These are three separate projects.  Both the implementation project (PrototypeIIP) and the Console project reference the interface project (IInterfaceProcessor.dll).  Yes the hard coded type names are for testing only.  I just am looking to get the basic structure down first.

Answer (score 0):

After Peter's response, I went back and tried being a bit more specific.

In PrototypeIIP.cs

```
public class IIPImplimentation : IInterfaceProcessor
```

to

```
public class IIPImplimentation : IIPInterfaces.IInterfaceProcessor
```

And in the Console program

```
IInterfaceProcessor myProcessor = Activator.CreateInstance(processor) as IInterfaceProcessor;
```

to

```
IIPInterfaces.IInterfaceProcessor myProcessor = Activator.CreateInstance(processor) as IIPInterfaces.IInterfaceProcessor;
```

It corrected the problem.  I'm not sure why it is looking at these as two separate types but it is.

Thanks Peter.